# Bulk import mongodb collection based on the same property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, nosql

I have an old database from mySql needs to be imported to mongoDb and I have created the new mongoDb schema of two collections as follows,

```
let Ticket = new Schema({
  ticket_no: String,
  title: String,
  logTickets: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'LogTicket'}]
});

let LogTicket = new Schema({
  user: String,
  timestamp: Date,
  log: String,
  ticket: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ticket'}
});
```

I already dealt with conversion to json and test it worked on `Ticket` , but for `LogTicket` for supplying each `Ticket`, I only have `ticket_no` as a linker of those two.

How to mass import `LogTicket` by `ticket_no` with mongoDb so it fills each `Ticket` collection?

Comment: You could alternately use [virtuals.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals). If you do that then you only need write to `LogTicket`, but if you don't you need to write to "both" `Ticket` and `LogTicket`. It typically makes more sense to store the foreign key in the "child", unless the intent is for the child to have multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

use populate function of mongoose

```
Ticket.
  findOne({ _id: refObjectId }).
  populate('logTickets').
  exec(function (err, ticket) {
    if (err) return throw err;
    console.log('The LogTickets are %s', ticket.logTickets);
  });
```

futher you read from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html